error: failed to select a version for `blake3`
Got errors when trying to do anchor build in my project:
Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error:     Updating git repository `https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave`
        Updating crates.io index
    error: failed to select a version for `blake3`.
        ... required by package `solana-program v1.17.3`
        ... which satisfies dependency `solana-program = "^1.17.3"` of package `anchor-lang v0.30.1`
        ... which satisfies dependency `anchor-lang = "^0.30.1"` of package `pain-transfer-hook v0.1.0 (/Users/ant/Desktop/pain-transfer-hook/programs/pain-transfer-hook)`
    versions that meet the requirements `^1.5.0` are: 1.5.4, 1.5.3, 1.5.2, 1.5.1, 1.5.0
    
    the package `solana-program` depends on `blake3`, with features: `digest` but `blake3` does not have these features.
     It has an optional dependency with that name, but that dependency uses the "dep:" syntax in the features table, so it does not have an implicit feature with that name.

I already added this patch in my root's Cargo.toml but didn't solve the issue:
[patch.crates-io]
solana-program = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave" }
solana-zk-token-sdk = { git = "https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave" }

Here are the dependencies I have for my project right now if that helps:
(tried adding solana-program = "=2.1.1" as well but in vain)
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
anchor-spl = "0.30.1"
spl-transfer-hook-interface = "0.9.0"


You are using the latest version of spl-transfer-hook-interface  which is probably pulling the newest version of solana-program that the anchor crates aren't using.
Try downgrading the spl-transfer-hook-interface crate in the Anchor.toml and build again.
[dependencies]
anchor-lang = "0.30.1"
anchor-spl = "0.30.1"
spl-transfer-hook-interface = "0.6.5"

Alternatively, you could play whack-a-mole trying to update the solana-program itself using
cargo update -p solana-program@<CURRENT_VERSION_TO_UPDATE>  --precise <VERSION_TO_CHANGE_TO>


Thanks for answering! Yea I want to keep using the latest version of the spl-transfer-hook-interface, so I just keep finding which version of the solana-program is the proper one to see if it works with the latest version of spl-transfer-hook-interface?

yep. List the versions of solana-program being pulled cargo tree | grep solana-program. Also try raising an issue in the spl github repo if you run out of luck.

blake3 maintainer here. This looks like a compatibility break on my part, originally in v1.5.2. I just pushed v1.5.5 to fix it. See this commit for details. You might need to remove a Cargo.lock file somewhere to pick up the new version, but other than that hopefully the fix just works?

I think that works after I also downgraded the spl-transfer-hook-interface back to "0.6.5"! But I think it's more on the anchor crates that are not using the latest version of solana-program as well, anyway thanks for your help!
